The provided project resource is not valid on "aws devicefarm create-test-grid-url" for Mobile device testing project
My goal is to start testing my website in real mobile device browsers from Amazon Device Farm. So, I need a "command_executor" for Appium web driver. I have a Mobile device testing project in AWS dashboard. I have its ARN. If I perform
aws devicefarm create-test-grid-url \
    --project-arn <arn copied from the dashboard> \
    --profile <profile name> \
    --region us-west-2 \
    --expires-in-seconds 300

The result is:

An error occurred (ArgumentException) when calling the CreateTestGridUrl operation: The provided project resource is not valid: <arn copied from the dashboard>

I try to list all my Mobile device testing projects by:
aws devicefarm list-test-grid-projects --profile <profile name> --region us-west-2

and receive an empty list.
Then I try to get my project details by:
aws devicefarm get-project \
    --arn <arn copied from the dashboard> \
    --profile <profile name> \
    --region us-west-2

and receive as expected:
{
    "project": {
        "arn": <arn copied from the dashboard>,
        "name": <Mobile device testing project name>,
        "created": "2024-10-10T17:30:04.591000+03:00"
    }
}

Then I try to create a new devicefarm project by:
aws devicefarm create-test-grid-project \
    --profile <profile name> \
    --region us-west-2 \
    --name <new testing project name> \
    --description "Project for web application testing"

Then I try to list test grid projects again and get the newly created project as the response. In the web dashboard I see that the new project was created in "Desktop browser testing projects" section, not "Mobile device testing projects". And for this project "aws devicefarm create-test-grid-url" works as expected.
I see that there are "test-grid-project" and "project".
So, how to get a test grid URL for Mobile device testing project?

I found the answer here: https://repost.aws/questions/QU-9AGg80OQKym6-2N-1DzoA/webdriver-instance-for-mobile-web-testing
Main point: mobile devices on AWS Device Farm aren't accessible remotely. You need to upload your tests to AWS. The "command_executor" URL should be the same for iOS and Android: "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"
